# Deriving URLs from date

Tags: bash, cron

I would like to automate a download of an image from a third party server with a CRON job and then upload the image to my website.

I have 2 issues:

First, the third party site changes the image name every day using the following logic:

http://thirdpartysite.com/ImageFinder.aspx?ReportID=FILENAME
where FILENAME is 26601 +14 for each day after 6 Oct 2014 (so 7 Oct would be 26615, 8 Oct would be 26629 etc).

How do I build this into a simple Linux bash script for use with wget?

Second, how do I upload this to my site via FTP (or similar) with the same script.

NOTE: I have permission to host the file on my site and have linked the original site / placed credit for the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestions of @Abhay, first get the timestamp of Oct 6, let's store it in the variable `$d0`:

```
d0=$(date +%s -d 20141006)
```

Then store the timestamp of a target date, say Oct 8 and store it in `$d1`:

```
d1=$(date +%s -d 20141008)
```

Then you can calculate the difference and apply the required arithmetic operations in `$((...))`, like this:

```
echo $((26601 + 14 * (d1 - d0) / 60 / 60 / 24))
# outputs: 26629
```

Answer (score 1):

The `date` command has one very good format: `%s`, which prints number of seconds since "epoch", which is the fixed date 1 January 1970, 00:00 UTC. I'll call it "timestamp". In combination with this, you can use the `-d date-string`, so that it prints the given date as number of seconds. Now you can take today's timestamp, subtract the timestamp of "6 Oct 2014" from it, and you get number of seconds between the two times. Now you can divide it by (60 * 60 * 24) to get it in number of days, and do further arithmetic to get the desired number, and make a file name out of it.

The date string formats that `-d` option takes are flexible, but as of now I am not sure whether it takes "6 Oct 2014" as is. Try a few permutations, or better, check the "info" page.